# Which way is better to invoke subtasks in Celery? group,delay each item,or using callback?

Tags: python, celery, yield

python 3.5
Celery 4.0.2
RabbitMq 3.6.10

I'm trying too climb some data, but I do not know which way is more appropriate.

The structure of data like a table, I need push subtask for each row.

Here's what I've used

- delay each each item:

  ```
  @app.task
  def task():
      for row in table:
          subtask.delay(row)

  @app.task
  def subtask(item):
      dosomething(item)
  ```
- using group

  ```
  @app.task
  def task():
      rows=[]
      for row in table:
          rows.append(row)
      group(subtask.s(row) for row in rows)()

  @app.task
  def subtask(item):
      dosomething(item)
  ```
- using group and yield

  ```
  def _task():
      for row in table:
          yield subtask(row).s()

  @app.task
  def task():
      group(_task())()

  @app.task
  def subtask(item):
      dosomething(item)
  ```

It's just a demo for my question,I've did some test for those code. The 3rd way looks like better.

Which way do you choose？

Any suggestion？